# how can I associate one variable with the other two (mysql)?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I have four tables in mysql (object, type, price, date)

all of them have two coloumns: "**id**" and "**variable**"

for example:

```
Object table
+----+-----------+
| id | variable  |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | shop1     |
+----+-----------+
|  2 | shop2     |
+----+-----------+

type table
+----+----------+
| id | variable |
+----+----------+
|  1 | lemon    |
+----+----------+
|  2 | potato   |
+----+----------+

Date table
+----+------------+
| id | variable   |
+----+------------+
|  1 | 2014-10-11 |
+----+------------+
|  2 | 2014-12-11 |
+----+------------+


price table
+----+------------+
| id | variable   |
+----+------------+
|  1 | 5000       |
+----+------------+
|  2 | 2000       |
+----+------------+
|  3 | 4000       |
+----+------------+
|  4 | 3000       |
+----+------------+
```

And what we really need in browser view:

```
Shop1:
+--------+------------+------------+
|        | 2014-10-11 | 2014-12-11 |
+--------+------------+------------+
| lemon  | 5000       | 3000       |
+--------+------------+------------+
| potato | 2000       | 4000       |
+--------+------------+------------+
```

Price is a variable and could be changed like an other variables (dates, type), columns of dates or types could be much more - (max - 5)

This table looks like Excel. But the price must depend on other variables, because other objects could use the same id of price.

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: How do you know that 5000 is the price of a lemon on that date? There doesn't appear to be any data to tell you so.

Comment: @almasshaikh Sorry, my question is "How could i do the view of object like an Excel table, and how could I connect cells object, price, date and type.

Comment: @Ben there I have the table of prices, and i could change it by smbd. So I wanted to give to cell the price on certain period (only on one type of the product).

Comment: I understand that @Igor; but you have no way of actually knowing. You have no way of associating the price for that period. So, it's all going to be completely random.

Comment: your database structure is not correct with the performance for large item list , you can do it with 2 tables 1 for holding the "shop" and second for the items holding columns with item name , date , price , item type. whatever.

Comment: @Noman Thanks.
But your structure will be like this:
If we have 3 items:
id_Obj|date1|type1|price1|date2|type2|price2|date3|type3|price3

\--

Comment: nope,columns will be the same like (ID,item_name,price,item_date) but your item list will consists of  multiple rows. like
----------------------------------------------------------------
`  ID | Item_name |  price | item_date
1. 1  | lemon     |   1200 | 2015-01-01 01:01:01
2. 2  | lemon     | 1200   | 2015-01-01 01:01:01 `

Comment: @Noman Sorry, that's my comment

But your structure will be like this:
If we have 3 items:
id_Obj|date1|type1|price1|date2|type2|price2|date3|type3|price3

-----and this will be like diagonal line

Answer (score -1):

First loop Through type table and get the ID

```
select * from type

Then Loop through ID's as $id
```

Then In loop you need to query each table for each required value.for example

```
select variable  from price where ID = $id
select variable  from date where ID = $id
```

Comment: Looking at the prices table this wouldn't be correct. How do you get the 4 differing prices by this method?

Comment: @Ben : assuming Id is unqiue and common for all I answered this , If its not unique no other go  , he must change entire table structure